# How to transfer files between two computers in the same LAN?

Tags: networking, file-transfer

I have to copy the whole disk to another computer in the same LAN (they're connected via wifi, however I could connect them with an ethernet cable).

What's the best way to transfer files?
I need to get this conditions satisfied:

- transfer between Windows/Windows or Ubuntu/Ubuntu computers
- verify every file with hash checksum
- possibility to manage files over 16GB
- velocity rate at around 10MBps or more would be great

Thanks a lot! <sub>and sorry if I used any bad expression</sub>

Comment: Is this a one-time event?

Comment: Yes, I have to do this only in very rare occasions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `rsync` fits all the requirements. It checks file integrity with md5 and if you are using an unencrypted connection you would easily get 10MBps (you'd probably get 50 MBps or so) over Gigabit Ethernet. The Windows port of rsync is called cwRsync.

Comment: Since being done over WiFi, logging the transfer would be recommended so it can be run twice to ensure no files were skipped/lost due to a potential momentary interruption of the WiFi signal _(`rsync` would check the log against the file tree before initiating the transfer)_. This is what I use within a [script](https://github.com/JW0914/Wikis/blob/master/Scripts%2BConfigs/TrueNAS/rsync-backup.sh) to create a 1:1 backup on long term storage: `rsync -avrt --human-readable --partial --stats --info=progress2 --log-file=backup-$(date '+%Y.%m.%d_%H:%M:%S').log ./from_dir ./to_dir`